# Does a Skylight need to be installed with the dedicated flashing system

Tags: windows, roof, flashing

I'm looking at this product

[image]

for a garden office roof but I could not find the corresponding flashing kit for the roof material I was planning to use, which is this:

[image]

The closest type of flashing I could find was this

[image]

but I'm not sure if it would be suitable for the chosen roofing material?

Comment: Is the roofing already installed and the skylight not installed yet? Or vice versa?

Comment: It has not been built yet.

Comment: You will need to look to the roof supplier for that material, IF they offer it.

Comment: I just searched for a kit and it looks like the one you have picture is by Velux, and it illustrates it on the same roof you plan to use. Perhaps that is the way to go.

Comment: @Jack I have concluded the same. I looked for Fakro flashings for my planned roof and they just don't exist. I'm going to go with Velux and change the roof style to the one in the picture (with the flashing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just searched for a kit and it looks like the one you have picture is by Velux, and it illustrates it on the same roof you plan to use. Perhaps that is the way to go.

It may tell you this in the instructions for the flashing install, but on the piece below the skylight, I would flatten out the standing ribs just a bit to help ease the membrane over the top of the lower piece. That way no sharp corner could pierce the membrane.